# Rename paperclip existing attachment file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have the following model in my Ruby on Rails app which uses paperclip for upload:

```
class SlideAudio < ApplicationRecord
  # == Extensions ============================================================
  Paperclip.interpolates :locale do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.locale
  end

  has_attached_file :audio,
    path: ":rails_root/public/slides/:attachment/:style/:locale/:id.:extension",
    url: "/slides/:attachment/:style/:locale/:id.:extension",
    processors: [:audio_compression],
    styles: {
      original: {},
      compressed_96k: {bitrate: '96k'}
    }
  # == Associations ==========================================================
  has_many :slide_slide_audios
  has_many :slides, through: :slide_slide_audios

  # == Validations ===========================================================
  validates_attachment :audio, content_type: {
    content_type: [
      'audio/mpeg',
      'audio/x-mpeg',
      'audio/mp3',
      'audio/x-mp3',
      'audio/mpeg3',
      'audio/x-mpeg3',
      'audio/mpg',
      'audio/x-mpg',
      'audio/x-mpegaudio'
    ]
  }
end
```

After uploading one audio I have two files:

1. `public/slides/audios/original/en/30381.mp3`
2. `public/slides/audios/compressed_96k/en/30381.mp3`

No I want to update all these file name to `18695.mp3`. How can I do this?

Comment: What is 18695 in `18695.mp3`?

Comment: Nothing, just a random numer that I typed.